# What is the most efficent way to save trained pytorch model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am training my collaborative filtering model using pytorch and saving the trained model to disk using the torch.save method. However, the resulting file is 5GB due to the massive dataset.

```
torch.save('model.pkl')
```

I have tried using the compress-pickle package, but it actually increases the file size. Is there a more efficient way to pickle the model and reduce the file size? If so, how can I achieve this?

UPDATE:

I'm using fastai's export method:

```
def export(self:Learner, fname='export.pkl', pickle_module=pickle, pickle_protocol=2):
    "Export the content of `self` without the items and the optimizer state for inference"
    if rank_distrib(): return # don't export if child proc
    self._end_cleanup()
    old_dbunch = self.dls
    self.dls = self.dls.new_empty()
    state = self.opt.state_dict() if self.opt is not None else None
    self.opt = None
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        #To avoid the warning that come from PyTorch about model not being checked
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
        torch.save(self, self.path/fname, pickle_module=pickle_module, pickle_protocol=pickle_protocol)
    self.create_opt()
    if state is not None: self.opt.load_state_dict(state)
    self.dls = old_dbunch
```

Comment: What is the command you use? `torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)`? The dataset size should not influece the size of the trained model

Comment: I'm using fastai export method that stores the whole learner object, I've added it's source code

Comment: What do you actually need though. From your question wording it sounds like you just want the trained model, for example to include it into a final application, but wouldn't need the whole state of the optimizer etc (which would be needed for contiinuing training at the exact same point)

Comment: Yes, all I need is to make predictions in the app. I've tried `torch.save(self.learn.model.state_dict(), model_name)`, but file size is almost the same.